# 500 Internal Server Error with SQLite PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm just following a tutorial of sqlite with php to create a data entry application. And I got an error 500 Internal Server Error with this simple line of code.

```
<h1><center>Create a DB in the same folder<br></center></h1>

<?php
        $database = new SQLite3('db.sqlite');
?>
```

When I comment down the line `//$database = new SQLite3('db.sqlite');` the error disappears. How can I use SQLite3 with my Php?

Comment: Please add the error mesage to your question. You should be able to find it in the error logs of your (apache / nginx) server.

Comment: Have you installed it?

Comment: check the error logs of your server to see the exact error. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1053424

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: or better yet, activate error reporting on your PHP instance so you can see the error message on screen, which is faster than going through the logs

Comment: "Fatal error: Class 'SQLite3' not found in /var/www/html/php/index.php on line 8" This is the error I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 500 Internal Service Error was fixed after I included :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

And the new error appeared:

```
Fatal error: Class 'SQLite3' not found in /var/www/html/php/index.php on line 8
```

I was able to fixed it by using PHP7 instead of PHP5, config nginx for the Php7 and install sqlite modules for Php7

```
sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

then check php-sqlite3

```
sudo apt-cache search php-sqlite3
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to install the support to PHP.

If you are using php5 try this: 
`sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite3`

If you are using php7 try this: `sudo apt-get install php7.0-sqlite3`

Enabling error messaging can help you too:
http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.error-reporting.php
[How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display/41641608)

Comment: 'sudo apt-get' will only work on ubuntu or debian linux systems.

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'SQLite3' not found in /var/www/html/php/index.php on line 8
This is the error I got.

Comment: @Jeremiah - do you see SQLite when you do a phpinfo() ?

Comment: After install sqlite3 did you restart the PHP ?

Comment: @FergalAndrews yes, I got "SQLite 3.x driver for PDO" & "SQLite3".
I already restart PHP/Nginx several times

Comment: @RenanMelo I enabled sqlite.dll & sqlite3.dll extensions in php.ini from CLI folder and it fixed the Error 500. 
Now the only error I'm getting is "Fatal error: Class 'SQLite3' not found in /var/www/html/php/index.php on line 8".

Comment: @Jeremiah - Are .dll files only for windows? Should you not be using .so?

Comment: @FergalAndrews I guess so, but when I enabled it the error 500 disappeared. And the only problem I'm gettin is that Fatal Error: class 'sqlite3' note found.

Comment: @Jeremiah - that is a bit odd :-)

Comment: @FergalAndrews oh wait, I just doubled check it. After I included the 'display errors' code that's the time Error 500 disappeared, not after I enable the dll extensions. I got confused because I did the 2 at the same time. My bad...